# How to let a Lambda call themself at the end with new parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new with AWS Lambda, and I'm building a music quiz game and I've encountered in an issue:

Basically, I have a Lambda that collect info for a specific artist by passing as parameter an ID. I'd like that this Lambda will run for example 100 times with 100 different IDs without putting them manually. Is there any clean way to do this?

Some extra info: I use Node.js 8.xx and my Lambda can be both invoked from an API of API Gateway and Lambda service itself.

Comment: Hello Roberto, welcome to stack overflow. Many people prefer seeing what you tried by yourself, some short code snippet of what is going wrong. I'm not to picky about that stuff, I find your question just fine as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Javascript Lambda

Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and passing in all the elements from an array:

```js
var musicID = [
  1001,
  2002,
  3003,
  4004
];

function logId(Id) {
  console.log(Id);
}

musicID.map((element) => logId(element));
```

Is thing what you are looking for?

Comment: If you wanna get even fancier, `musicID.map(logId);` works equally well ;)

Comment: I tried and it "works". But I can't achieve what I wanted because my Lambda functions take too time complete, so I got the TimeOut from this function. I'm doing invoking only two Lambdas at time in order to achieve what I wanted. Thank you